# I Want to install PHP 7.4 on Oracle Linux 8 with the PHP OCI8 extension

Tags: php, oci8, oraclelinux

I tried a lot of thing on internet but didn't worked, and i follow this steps on oracle linux documentation:

[client documentation](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-instant-client.html)

[php oci documentation](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html#InstallPHPOCI8)

commands with the follow erro:

`sudo dnf install oracle-instantclient-release-el8`

`sudo dnf install oracle-instantclient-basic`

erro:
No match for argument: oracle-instantclient-basic
Error: Unable to find a match: oracle-instantclient-basic

`dnf module list php`

`sudo dnf install @php:7.4`

`sudo dnf install oraclelinux-developer-release-el8 oracle-instantclient-release-el8`

`sudo dnf module enable php:7.4 php-oci8`

erro:
Error: Problems in request:
missing groups or modules: php-oci8

Comment: It's not clear from what you've posted exactly what has worked and what has not. It seems that only the installation of the PHP-OCI8 module has failed. In any case, PHP 7.4 is no longer supported. You should consider installing PHP 8.2

Answer (score 0):

Is this an aarch64 system? If so, some of those RPMs are not available for that platform.